# Currency Converter API that stores rates in database table

Tags: java

I need api in java that create a table and update currency rates on daily bases in that table  from which i will able to fetch required currency rate any time. currently i am using api that converts currency at real time and it is working fine but i need updated currency rates on daily bases in db table.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can yourself make a utility just use quartz to schedule the updation process may be 6 hourly the same code you are using for api will work.